# Using MySQL when I retrieve a hashed users password from my database it is comes out as 1.

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to use PHP to create a CSV file for the user. So far this works as I get the file with the headers in. But when I comes to having the data in it from the SQL query, nothing works. I have read about 6 threads on here regarding how to do this but none of them return any data, the query works on another page returning data. Here is my code;

```
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
  $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
  fputcsv($output, array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20'));  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tblOrders";  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
  {  
    fputcsv($output, $row); 
  }
  fclose($output);
```

I get the 1 ... 20 headers (which will be replaced with the actual headers if anything ever gets up and running. Everything I read on here and other sites points to the fact that the above should work. Is there something else I need to do to to allow the SQL to output to the file? I have spent the last 2 days trying to get this working and now am just going around in circles. So I am hoping there is someone that will be able to help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title came from a question that I found the answer two while typing the question... the title is so very wrong.

Comment: So what is the exact problem? WHat you expect and what you get?

Comment: I expect a CSV file to be the output with the headers of 1 to 20 then each row there after the result of the SQL call. What I get is a CSV with the headers 1 to 20 an nothing else.

Comment: Are you sure your query executes correctly? DId you check errors? Did you check value of `$result`?

Comment: Where is `$conn` defined?

Comment: Tried it on a separate page to just display the result and it worked ok.

Comment: Separate page is a __separate page__. There can be tons of changes between current page and separate. `var_dump($result);`, what do you see?

Comment: $conn is in an include file result holds;

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 1,2017-11-12,"Agent","The Firm","Boss",1442,7900,info@thefirm.com,Collection,1,0,0,400,0,,0,"No notes for this order",ADV400,ASWE3434,endloc

Comment: `$result` __cannot__ hold what you printed. Because `$result` is a result of a query execution.

Comment: The var dump show object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(20) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
```

instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. It returns an [enumerated array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) like the one you're using for your headers, rather than an associative (key/value) array.